# Room Livedata returns incorrect values

Tags: android, sql, android-room, android-livedata

I have an audio recorder app, where I enable the user to mark certain points in his recordings with predefined markers. For that purpose I have a MarkerEntity, which is the type of Marker, and a MarkTimestamp, the point at which the user marks a given recording. These entities are connected via a Relation, called MarkAndTimestamp.

```
@Entity(tableName = "markerTable")
data class MarkerEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "markerName") val markerName: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "markerTimeTable")
data class MarkTimestamp(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "mid") val mid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "recordingId") val recordingId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "markerId") val markerId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "markTime") val markTime: String
)

data class MarkAndTimestamp(
    @Embedded val marker: MarkerEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uid",
        entityColumn = "markerId"
    )
    val markTimestamp: MarkTimestamp
)
```

The insertion of this data works flawlessly, I checked this via DB Browser for SQLite and Android Debug Database. The problem arises, when I want to display all marks for a recording. I fetch the entries with the following SQL statement.

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM markerTimeTable INNER JOIN markerTable ON markerTimeTable.markerId=markerTable.uid WHERE markerTimeTable.recordingId = :key")
fun getMarksById(key: Int): LiveData<List<MarkAndTimestamp>>
```

What ends up happening is, that if the user uses a Marker more than once, all marks created with that Marker have the same MarkerTimestamp row attached to them, specificially, the last row to be inserted with that Marker. The weird thing is, this only happens in the app using Livedata. Using the same query in DB Browser for SQLite returns the correct and desired data.

This is the stored data (correct)

[MarkTimestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXYd8.png)

[MarkerEntities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dIw3.png)

And this is the Livedata returned at this point (incorrect)

```java
[
MarkAndTimestamp(marker=MarkerEntity(uid=1, markerName=Mark), markTimestamp=MarkTimestamp(mid=6, recordingId=2, markerId=1, markTime=00:05)),
MarkAndTimestamp(marker=MarkerEntity(uid=2, markerName=zwei), markTimestamp=MarkTimestamp(mid=5, recordingId=2, markerId=2, markTime=00:03)),
MarkAndTimestamp(marker=MarkerEntity(uid=1, markerName=Mark), markTimestamp=MarkTimestamp(mid=6, recordingId=2, markerId=1, markTime=00:05))
]
```

I also get the following build warning

```
warning: The query returns some columns [mid, recordingId, markerId, markTime] which are not used by de.ur.mi.audidroid.models.MarkAndTimestamp. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: mid, recordingId, markerId, markTime, uid, markerName. Fields in de.ur.mi.audidroid.models.MarkAndTimestamp: uid, markerName. - getMarksById(int) in de.ur.mi.audidroid.models.MarkerDao
```

Why does Room return the wrong data and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I still don't know what caused the behaviour described in my original post. My guess is, that the realtion data class and the SQL query interfered in some way, producing the cinfusing and incorrect outcome.

I solved my problem nonetheless. I needed to change

```
data class MarkAndTimestamp(
    @Embedded val marker: MarkerEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "uid",
        entityColumn = "markerId"
    )
    val markTimestamp: MarkTimestamp
)
```

to

```
data class MarkAndTimestamp(
    @Embedded val marker: MarkerEntity,
    @Embedded val markTimestamp: MarkTimestamp
)
```

This makes sure, that all fields returned by the query are included in the data class.